# Pythonic way to check if at least one number of a list is in a tuple

Tags: python

I have one tuple and one list:

```
t = (1, 2, 9)
l = range(2, 8)
```

and I want to check if there's at least one element of the list is in the tuple. I tried to use:

```
if (2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7) in l:
    return True
```

but it works only for the number *2*.

Now I'm using:

```
if 2 in l or 3 in l or 4 in l or 5 in l or 6 in l or 7 in l:
    return True
```

but I think that's not the best way to do it.
Is there a way to shrink this piece of code to make it more elegant?

Comment: Where are you interacting with `t` or any of its elements? Anyway, it's `any(item in l for item in t)` (or `any(item in t for item in l)`, if you wanted the opposite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply want:

```
any(e in t for e in l)
```

Comment: I didn't know the fuction *any*, thank you!

Comment: If `l` and `t` are sufficiently large, it makes sense to use a `set` for `t`

Comment: @schwobaseggl sure, but I think that is only an ancillary point.